# Python: extracting an integer from json using split

Tags: python, json, split, integer

I'm trying to extract the month number from dates in JSON files as an integer. The dates are formatted like this: `"1990-12-01"`
The problem is that I'm getting extra characters that are incompatible with integers. I'm obviously missing something dumb. Here's an example of my output:

```
['12']
```

Here's my code:

```
f = open('data/file1.json')
data = json.load(f)
birthmonth = (data['people'][0]['birthDate'])
newmonth = birthmonth.split('-')[1:2]
print(newmonth)
```

And here's what the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "copyright" : "All Rights Reserved.",
  "people" : [ {
    "id" : 84755,
    "primaryNumber" : "21",
    "birthDate" : "1990-12-01",
    "currentAge" : 29,
    "active" : true,
    "currentRole" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "office"
    },
    "primaryBase" : {
      "code" : "R",
      "name" : "Recall"
    }
  } ]
}
```

What can I do to produce output that's pure integers?
Thanks,

Comment: Specifying JSON here is a bit of a red herring, since you're ultimately just splitting a string that's been *parsed* for you from JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just cast to int and extreact item from list because when slicing with `[1:2]` you slice notation returns a list:

so do:

```
print(int(newmonth[0]))
```

or just refactor the code even better:

```
with open('data/file1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    birthmonth = (data['people'][0]['birthDate'])
    newmonth =int(birthmonth.split('-')[1])
    print(newmonth)
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. I went off to do something else while I waited to see if anyone would answer. But as far as I can tell, this magically appeared instantly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The slicing notation `[1:2]` returns a sublist, from index 1 to 2 (excluded), so it takes your data but as a list, you'd better use one these options

- **date operation**, directly parse the content as a `date`

  ```
  newmonth = datetime.strptime(birthmonth, "%Y-%m-%d").month
  ```
- *string operations* to avoid as you don't check the data consistency

  - Splitting on `dash`, which gives a list of string, from which you need the 2nd box

    ```
    birthmonth.split('-')                    # ['1990', '12', '01']
    birthmonth.split('-')[1]                 # '12'
    newmonth = int(birthmonth.split('-')[1]) # 12
    ```
  - Slicing to retrieve a specific part of the string

    ```
    birthmonth[5:7] # '12'
    newmonth = int(birthmonth[5:7]) # 12
    ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool for the job, [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(data["people"][0]["birthDate"], "%Y-%m-%d").month
12
```

This gives you the added benefit of data validation. Blindly slicing and splitting strings might accidentally return bogus results if the input is not in year-month-day format.